# Read a value being manipulated in different thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to read a static property from a static class, which is being modified from a different thread.

Basically I have this static class:

```
public static class Progress{
     public static int currentProgress{get; set;}
}
```

and this thread manipulating the currentProgress:

```
private void Job(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
         Progress.currentProgress = i;
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

While this is running, I have a HttpHandler trying to access this progress (every few seconds), like so:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.Write(Progress.currentProgress.toString());
    context.Response.End();
}
```

But the currentProgress is set to it's initialvalue here, while the workThread is working, and only when done, is the currentProgress updated.

I realize that this is probably a question of sync'ing the threads - but I can't quite seem to find the easiest way to accomplish this. Help please ;)

Comment: This should work. There is no need to synchronise access to an `int` (unless the new value of the int is computed from the its old value).

Comment: how are you accessing the httphandler, i'm assuming javascript polling the url with ajax to get your status? or just manually refreshing it?

Comment: yes, using jQuery ajax to poll it;)

Comment: If you just increment the progress you can use the Interlocked.Increment method

Comment: Actually I don't just increment, this was just for simplicity, I use a total variable in place of '100' and calculate a percentage to assign to currentProgress

Comment: -.- let's all have a laugh at my stupidity. It's worked all along - I was calculating a percentage using an int (i/total)*100 - of course this always equals 0 - until it reaches 100 -.- I hate myself sometimes... :) Thanks all who contributed though

Answer (score 1):

First step is to declare your static value as volatile.

Comment: this didn't seem to change anything (other then I had to change it from and automatic property to a regular one)